# Swift 2.2 syntax error: Cannot call value of non-function type 'UITableView!'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using to Tab gesture in UITableView cell but following error occur.

"Cannot call value of non-function type 'UITableView!'"
I am using the following code which I inherited from my previous Objective C project:

```
    var p: CGPoint = sender.locationInView(self.tableView)
    var indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView(forRowAtPoint:p)
    var buttonTag: Int = indexPath.row

    var selectView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DropDownSelectionViewController") as? DropDownSelectionViewController

    var selectWithNaviBar: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: selectView!)

    if (buttonTag == TEAM_ROW) {
        getPeoplesWithMenuType(TEAM)
    }else{
        if (buttonTag == OFFICES_ROW)  {
            selectView?.menuName = OFFICES_MENU
          //  selectView?.isMultipleSelection = yes
        }else if(buttonTag == CATEGORIES_ROW){

        }else if(buttonTag == INTERNAL_GROUPS_ROW){

        }
    }
```

I would appreciate if someone could help.

Comment: It's `tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(p)` (self is not needed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
self.tableView(forRowAtPoint:p)
```

is the source of problems. 
You probably want `self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(p)`